# "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" error trying to connect to OpenSSH on Windows machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh

I'm trying to set up an SSH server on my Windows2k8 server. I used the instructions found [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH). Here's the verbose output:

```
steves-air:~ steve$ ssh steve@mydomain.ca -v
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mydomain.ca port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/steve/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

So far I'm able to get a network connection, indicating that it's not a firewall problem. As a test, I also tried running sshd under cygwin. I was able to get a terminal prompt with that. I'd prefer to use OpenSSH though, since I want to get it working with powershell.

I tried setting the logging level to DEBUG, but i'm not getting any other troubleshooting info from there.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

*edit: Just realized i should mention. I tried putting a hosts.allow file in the %programdata%/ssh directory. That didn't help and I'm not sure if its applicable in this case.

*edit2: I tried running sshd in interactive mode per the troubleshooting steps from [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Troubleshooting-Steps). Windows came up with an appcrash when i tried to connect. Here's the output before it crashed:

```
PS C:\Program Files\OpenSSH> .\sshd.exe -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.9, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:XXX
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXX
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:XXX
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
Connection from 192.168.1.39 port 51410 on 192.168.1.3 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version 
OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.9
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 10684
```

Comment: what about with -vvv ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is "you can't get there from here." I found a closed issue on the git which says that [w2k8 standard is not supported](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1120). I tried installing on a different server that has 2k8R2 on it and that worked easily.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you could try Cygwin's port of OpenSSH. If you want to just check and see if it works, you can try this one:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/CygSSH

It does require Windows PowerShell v2 on Vista/Server 2008, though, so you would need to install that first (which you should hopefully have already).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, check this one.

I was able to find the root cause with the help of `systemctl status sshd`.

My `/etc/hosts.deny` did not have a newline in the end.

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/hosts.deny       
# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts that are _not_ allowed to access the system.
#                  See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: some.host.name, .some.domain
#             ALL EXCEPT in.fingerd: other.host.name, .other.domain
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
# The PARANOID wildcard matches any host whose name does not match its
# address.
#
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID%                                                                                                                                                                                                     ➜  ~ 
➜  ~ ssh localhost             
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ sudo systemctl status sshd 
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-10-14 16:45:43 IST; 20s ago
  Process: 11488 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11494 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─11494 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Oct 14 16:45:43 mani-8681 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct 14 16:45:43 mani-8681 sshd[11494]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 14 16:45:43 mani-8681 sshd[11494]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 14 16:45:43 mani-8681 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 14 16:45:54 mani-8681 sshd[11555]: warning: /etc/hosts.deny, line 15: missing newline or line too long
Oct 14 16:45:54 mani-8681 sshd[11555]: warning: /etc/hosts.deny, line 15: all the subsequent rules will be ignored
Oct 14 16:45:54 mani-8681 sshd[11555]: refused connect from 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)
```

Adding a newline in the end fixed the issue.

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/hosts.deny
# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts that are _not_ allowed to access the system.
#                  See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: some.host.name, .some.domain
#             ALL EXCEPT in.fingerd: other.host.name, .other.domain
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
# The PARANOID wildcard matches any host whose name does not match its
# address.
#
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID
➜  ~ ssh localhost date
Password:
Mon Oct 14 16:51:56 IST 2019
```